# Hibernate - How to persist many to many entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 entities. User and Role. Relationship between them is many to many **unidirectional**.

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinTable(name = "uber_user_role",
        joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "uber_user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

When persisting a new User entity, Role entity with an ID of 1 should be associated to User. So far my code looks like this:

```
Role role = em.getReference(Role.class, 1L);
        user.getRoles().add(role);
        em.persist(user);
```

It works, but generates 3 sql statements

1. Select statement for role getting role object
2. Insert statement for inserting new User entity
3. Insert statement for inserting relationship between them in junction table

Is there a better way to achieve this kind of behavior? I think first select statement is redundant? Can we instead get a proxy to role object and only do 2 inserts then?

Answer (score 0):

```
First up all the user and role mostly have oneToMany relationship.

Second thing above you mention like three steps we need to follow there is no change.

But, the role object selection you can get role object reference instead of getting object.

In hibernate JPA repository queryfindById it will help you to get object reference.
```

Comment: I am confused, how can you make one to many relationship between them if you persist role entity as well as user entity. User can have multiple roles as role can have multiple users.

Comment: They are not the steps that you follow, they are generated sql statements from the code above. I am aware of JPA repositories, but i want to write my own queries to get better feel and control over them. Do you know corresponding  code on session or entity manager layer?

Comment: I said mostly have one to many not am say should be. It's depends on requirement and mostly i have used.